# RAM module not detected

Tags: ram

I have an hp notebook 14-am003nk under ubuntu 18.04. I had 4G of RAM in one slot, when I added another RAM in the free slot it was not detected, or maybe it's detected but wrongfully.

Here is the output of some commands:

```
$ uname -a
Linux HP 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ sudo dmidecode -t memory | egrep "^\s+Size"
Size: 4096 MB
Size: No Module Installed
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 4GiB
 *-bank:0
      description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
      product: HMT451S6BFR8A-PB
      vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
      physical id: 0
      serial: 23138687
      slot: Bottom-Slot 1(left)
      size: 4GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
 *-bank:1
      description: SODIMM DDR Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns) [empty]
      product: HMT351S6CFR8C-PB
      vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
      physical id: 1
      serial: 11131631
      slot: Bottom-Slot 2(right)
      clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)

$ sudo dmidecode -t memory | egrep "^\s+Size"
    Size: 4096 MB
    Size: No Module Installed
```

Comment: It's because you've mixed and matched DDR3 and DDR memory sticks together. Can't do that.

Comment: The vendor says that it's a DDR3 and I verified that by looking for the reference online.

Comment: It's a different product ID number. Try switching the RAM sticks to each others socket and see if the bank 0/1 info changes. Report back to @heynnema for me to see your results.

Comment: update... I suspect that the two RAM sticks aren't compatible with each other. Try my previous comment to eliminate something else.

Comment: @heynnema I previously tried switching the RAMs and also using just the new RAM but it didn't work.

Comment: The new RAM is defective.

Comment: yeah, I just returned it today.